# Is it possible to create a document that contains a collection when a button is clicked?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I create a document with 2 fields in a top collection when a button saved is clicked.
Could somehow create at the same time that a create the document, a collection inside this document? I want to create an empty messages collection for each document is created.

```
public createSavedDoc(title: string, tags: string[]): void {

    const savedFields = {
      title: title,
      tags: tags
    }

    this.db.collection('saved').add(savedFields)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Cloud Firestore, there is really no such thing as an "empty" collection.  A collection will immediately exist when the first document is written to it, and it will suddenly disappear from the console when the last document is deleted.  Collections are just containers for documents, and querying a collection that doesn't exist is exactly the same thing as a querying a collection with 0 documents.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Doug, in my case where i want to create a messages collection in the current collection document i selected, i should create the collection the same time when i want to add the message document in it?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you don't have to do anything to create the collection other than write the first document into to it.  You really don't have much of a choice in the matter since it's all automatic.

Comment: I am just not sure how the path should look like since the collection that will be created has no name. For example if i want to create a messages collection document in saved collection should it be like -> this.db.collection(`saved/${savedTitle}/messages`).add ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Just refer to the collection using the name you would like. You have to give it a name.